# CSS Returned to the line without cutting the words

Tags: html, css

I have a div that contains a text. I want my text to be displayed on several lines when it is very long but without cutting the last word of each line. for example if the last word of a line i is foobar, I want this word to be displayed in a new line if the size is not enough instead of displaying foo in this line and bar in the next line.

for this purpose I tried:

```
div{
    word-break: break-all;
 }
```

also

```
div{
  word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

but it does not work

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure to understand what you exactly want to do here.

Indeed : 
`word-wrap:break-word;` will break very long word onto two lines (words that are longer than the `width` of your `div`)

and `word-break: break-all;` will break your words at any point (read at any letter) when it arrives at the end of a `div`

`word-wrap: normal;` may actually be what you want, but that's the default value of the property